# Import xml file of pages to wordpress and set the parent page or permalink

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, permalinks

I want to import a bunch of pages (to WordPress site) using xml import. I want to make sure all of these pages have a particular permalink (parent page) e.g. `/some/info/page_name/`

full example: `www.foo.com/some/info/page_name/`

For other variables such as whether the page is immediately (upon import) published or draft, I use: $post_status = "draft". And for post type = page I use:

```
$post_type = "page";
```

Is there a variable I can use that sets the parent page?

e.g.

```
$post_parent = "/some/info/";
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer to this myself:
On the WordPress site: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta
the variable "post_parent" is actually the ID of the page/post. Therefore, the variable is number, not a string.
By searching in my WordPress theme SQL database, I was able to find the the ID of a page.
I did this by searching for all parent IDs:

```
 select distinct post_parent from wp_posts where post_parent != 0;
```

Then I created a new page (on the Admin side) with the parent page I want and then publish it, then I did the above command again. (Last ID in list is now the ID of the newly created page: here 27091).
Then checked which is the post_parent id of that page:

```
 select post_parent from wp_posts where ID=27091;
```

Which gave me the ID of the post_parent. Then I set this in the variable for the import.